# Some merge candidates for Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual-booting questions

Tags: discussion, duplicates

This looked a bit unwieldy for flagging, so I'm posting this here instead.   I've looked through several of the dual-boot questions, trying to find ones that looked like duplicates.  I have found several that might be candidates for merging.  These are potentially useful because they deal with the current version of Windows, and it seems like this might be a popular topic for new questions centered around 11.04. (Now, I'm assuming that 10.x or 11.04 doesn't make much of a difference for dual-booting.)

***Possible merge candidates?***

*[dual-boot] windows7 and Ubuntu (same drive)*

[Installing Ubuntu 10.10 / Windows 7 dual boot confusion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15936/installing-ubuntu-10-10-windows-7-dual-boot-confusion)

[How to avoid problems when installing Ubuntu and Windows 7 in dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18560/how-to-avoid-problems-when-installing-ubuntu-and-windows-7-in-dual-boot)

[What is the proper way to Windows 7/Ubuntu 10.10 Dual-Triple Boot Partitioning for Laptop OEM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19354/what-is-the-proper-way-to-windows-7-ubuntu-10-10-dual-triple-boot-partitioning-fo)

[Unable to dual-boot Windows 7 and Kubuntu 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23331/unable-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-kubuntu-10-10)

[Installing Windows 7 on a Ubuntu 10.10 System](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21439/installing-windows-7-on-a-ubuntu-10-10-system)

[questions about dual-boot install Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 on same hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20189/questions-about-dual-boot-install-ubuntu-10-04-and-windows-7-on-same-hard-drive)

*[dual-boot] two separate hard drives*

[2 hard drives / HD1: UBuntu HD2: Win7. best practice isolated os's for dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30799/2-hard-drives-hd1-ubuntu-hd2-win7-best-practice-isolated-oss-for-dual-boot)

[Windows 7 can't boot with Ubuntu on different hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23830/windows-7-cant-boot-with-ubuntu-on-different-hard-drive)

Comment: Interesting list you've compiled, we'll (mods) have to peel through these.